# Angular2 Default Change Detection

Tags: angular

How does Change Detection works in Angular2 when changeDetection Strategy is set to "ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default"?
Does it check for all the bindings (by only reference) in template, and trigger re-render if any reference has been changed?

Comment: Take a look to this article : https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

The `default change detection strategy` will run change detection for all the bindings. It will not only look for reference changes, but for property changes on your model as well.

For example running the following code will change the name in the template after the `changeName()` method is run, even though only the `name` property changes, not the `person` reference.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{person.name}}</h1>
    <button (click)="changeName()">Change name!</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  person = { name: 'Foo' };

  changeName() {
    this.person.name = 'Bar';
  } 
}
```

Comment: It is still checking the reference to the property that has been bound in the template. As in above example "person.name" has been bound in the template.